# How can I deal with lots of precision warning flags?

Tags: objective-c, c, precision

The following simple code

```
int generated;
generated = (random() % 100) + 1;
```

gives a warning flag for loss of precision, 'long' to 'int', so I have been correcting it by rewriting the assignment code as

```
generated = ((int)random() % 100) + 1;
```

Is this a valid way of correcting the problem or am I just covering up errors elsewhere?

Comment: That solves your problem as long as you only need an int. random() returns a long, and by storing it in an int it throws an error. Casting it to (int) is a perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use long for your constants:

```
generated = (random() % 100L) + 1L;
```

Note that this assume that generated is long.

**EDIT:** Since generated is an int, you just need to cast it after you are done:

```
generated = (int)((random() % 100L) + 1L);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, `generated` is just an int, it is in the OP but not in a code block.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. I know I can re-type generated to a 'long' but I was trying to stay true to the code the author was telling me to use in the book. Seems like a lost cause. I get a lot of errors the author doesn't and I am stuck trying to figure out how to correct them.

Comment: @Aubrey Todd: Does the autor says which compiler/version he is using? Try using the same compiler, with the same compiling flags and you should be ok.

Comment: He is using Xcode 3.0 and I am using Xcode 4.0.2. I could reinstall 3.0 but I would like to become versatile enough in my coding that I can overcome minor problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you will be truncating the `random()` result too early. You need to cast the mod operation.

```
int generated;
generated = (int)(random() % 100) + 1;
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I was truncating the random number itself and not the final value which makes sense now, Thanks for your help.